# How do i position one image on the right top beside of the other image?

Tags: html, css

I have two images one large image and a small image. The small image has to come on the right top of the large image, not on the image but beside the image. 
When you scale now the small image comes over the large image but it has to be on the right top beside.

```
/*this is the large image*/
#afbeeldinglaptop > img{
width: 92%;
text-align: center;
max-width: 600px;
display: block;
margin: 0 auto;
}
/*this is the small image*/
.betrouwbaar{
width: 70%;
max-width: 1300px;
position: absolute;
text-align: right;
margin-top: -330px;

}
<!--This is my html-->
<div id="afbeeldinglaptop">
<img src="img/laptop.png" alt="laptop" />
<div class="betrouwbaar"><img src="img/wolkje.png" alt="wolkje" />
</div>

</div>
```

Has anyone an idea?

Comment: maybe so http://jsfiddle.net/soledar10/Ls75jbke/

Comment: yes it is what i want, but now when you scale the small image comes on top of the large image? How?